# Dual of lisse complexes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be scheme of finite type over a field of characteristic $p$. Let $L$ be a lisse  bounded complex of étale $\mathbf{Z}/l$-sheaves (with $l$ a prime different from $p$). I remind you that this means that $H^i(L)$ is étale locally isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}/l^{n_i}$.

We write $L^\vee = \underline{RHom}(L,\mathbf{Z}/l)$

I want to understand the following claim (cf. http://www-personal.umich.edu/~takumim/MATH731.pdf lemma $18.9$ page 66) : $H^i(L^\vee) \cong H^{-i}(L)^\vee$

Here the argument that is given : we can assume that $H^i(L) \cong \mathbf{Z}/l^{n_i}$ by working locally but $\underline{RHom}(\mathbf{Z}/l,\mathbf{Z}/l) \cong \mathbf{Z}/l$ so this implies the result .

I don't understand why $\underline{RHom}(\mathbf{Z}/l,\mathbf{Z}/l) \cong \mathbf{Z}/l$ nor why this implies the result ?